# Supply default values to all columns, tables, databases in sql-2012 express

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, default-value

I am working on the **sql 2012 server express edition**.

I want to assign the default values to all columns of all tables in all user databases.

> 1. All numeric, int, smallint, tinyint etc   0 default value
> 2. All date related fields '01-jan-1900' default value
> 3. All character fields (Varchar etc)  ''  default value
> 4. All Logical fields  0 default value

I do not want to do it with table designer. How to do it with command or stored procedure.

This default value is not to be set for the primary key fields and auto increment fields (Identity Columns).

I am new to SQL programming and all the times I have to take care for the NULL values and for my working the NULL have no significance other than thier default values. It is to be done for the all existing tables.

Comment: Get all user defined tables, get their columns, check if default already exists, generate dynamic sql to update default, use `sp_exec` to execute it?

Comment: This is an unusual requirement. May we know why you want to do this? Unless your tables all have primary keys or unique keys, just inserting two rows with all defaults will produce an invalid table with dupes.

Comment: @John Saunders This default value is not to be set for the primary key fields and auto increment fields (Identity Columns).
I am new to SQL programming and all the times I have to take care for the NULL values and for my working the NULL have no significance other than thier default values. 

It is to be done for the all existing tables.

Comment: This looks like an X-Y problem to me. Why do you feel you need to do this? Nulls are really useful.

Comment: It's pretty unusual for every date column (as just one example) to require the same default value. Imagine a column named "contract_start_date". If your company was founded in 1985, then your proposed default value constitutes a false fact. Don't store false facts; store true facts. A poorly considered default value can break a lot of sensible constraints. I agree with @TonyHopkinson--this looks like an X-Y problem.

Comment: Of course my requirement may appear unusual. But is has turned my need. when we query some records then I have to check for the field not being empty and also the field not being NULL. For

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson I agree NULL are useful and tells about fields virginity.
But when I query then I have to check for 2 things the field not being empty and also the field not being NULL. Every where i have to check for NULL MAX(), MIN(), Values assigned to variable (in VB). The front end grid displays NULL for each NULL value in the table.(Annoys User) Needs check every time, every field.

 Above all it is the programmer how he arranges the things and how he picks them up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a solution like this for each database:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

SELECT
    @SQL = @SQL +
    'UPDATE [' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + '] SET [' + c.name + '] = ' +
    CASE
        WHEN t.name IN ('int', 'bigint', 'bit', 'decimal', 'money', 'numeric', 'smallint', 'smallmoney', 'tinyint', 'float', 'real') THEN '0'
        WHEN t.name IN ('char', 'varchar', 'text') THEN ''''''
        WHEN t.name IN ('nchar', 'nvarchar', 'ntext') THEN 'N'''''
        WHEN t.name IN ('date', 'datetime', 'datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'smalldatetime', 'time') THEN 'CAST(''1900-01-01'' AS ' + t.name + ')'
        ELSE '0'
    END +
    ' WHERE [' + c.name + '] IS NULL; '
FROM
    sys.schemas s 
    INNER JOIN
    sys.objects o ON s.[schema_id] = o.[schema_id]
    INNER JOIN
    sys.columns c ON o.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN
    sys.types t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id AND c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE
    o.[type] = 'U'
    AND
    c.is_identity <> 1
    -- If you want to apply it to only one table use this:
    AND
    o.name = 'yourTable'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Thanks to @shA.t for posting this nice code. It helped to be set the existing Null values to their defaults. I was trying to set the defaults for the rows that will be added later. If it is tough to set all of the database table's default values in one go, then we will go step by step. First help me to set defaults to one table's columns. I am unaware of this type of coding ( like  sys.schemas, c.system_type_id etc) so I am asking for help. Hopefully you will reply.

Comment: @user3328343 This is dynamic SQL, you can filter the query for your purpose ;).